# Quads with some nodes shifted

Tags: finite-element, gmsh

I'm new to gmsh. I would like to produce a mesh of quads where some nodes are shifted.
I managed to have construct a structured mesh of quads. However, I would like now to shift some of the points to produce the mesh i'm interested in as in the figure
[image]

Can someone help me? or have any different idea on how to do this?

This is the code for structured quads.

```
import gmsh
import math
import sys
#=======================
model = gmsh.model
factory = model.geo
#==============
gmsh.initialize()
gmsh.option.setNumber(“General.Terminal”, 1)
#=============
lc = 1e-2
p1 = factory.addPoint(0, 0 , 0, lc, 1)
p2 = factory.addPoint(1, 0 , 0, lc, 2)
p3 = factory.addPoint(1, 1.1, 0, lc, 3)
p4 = factory.addPoint(0, 1.1, 0, lc, 4)
#==============
l1 = factory.addLine(1, 2, 1)
l2 = factory.addLine(3, 2, 2)
l3 = factory.addLine(3, 4, 3)
l4 = factory.addLine(4, 1, 4)
domain = factory.addCurveLoop([4, 1, -2, 3], 1)
#==================
factory.addPlaneSurface([domain])
#creating nodes
factory.mesh.setTransfiniteCurve(l1, 6)
factory.mesh.setTransfiniteCurve(l2, 6)
factory.mesh.setTransfiniteCurve(l3, 6)
factory.mesh.setTransfiniteCurve(l4, 6)
#I don’t understand this command??
factory.mesh.setTransfiniteSurface(1, “Left”, [1,2,3,4])
#==================Recombine the triangles into quads
factory.mesh.setRecombine(2, 1)
gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()
themesh = model.mesh.generate(dim=2)
gmsh.write(“quad.msh”)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of third party libraries like meshio to read the generated mesh file using meshio's read function

```
import meshio
import numpy as np

# Load the mesh from a Gmsh file
mesh = meshio.read("quad.msh")
```

Then write your logics for moving the points, In this case, you want to move to move certain points by a factor in y direction

```
h = 1.0/N


# generate a list of Co-ordinates where transformation is needed
cord = np.arange(0+h , 1 , h)
cord_change = coord[::2]  ##every second point

# Loop over all the points and modify the y-coordinate if the point is not on the edge of the unit square
for i in range(len(points)):
    if points[i][0] > 0 and points[i][0] < 1 and points[i][1] > 0 and points[i][1] < 1:
        if points[i][0] in cord_change and points[i][1] in cord_change:
            points[i][1] += 0.1

# Update the points in the mesh
mesh.points = points
```

Note : I did not have time to check the logic, but the pseudocode should work fine

Then write the file to gmsh format using the updated points.

```
# Write the modified mesh back to a Gmsh file
meshio.write("modified_mesh.msh", mesh, file_format="gmsh")
```

Comment: Please accept the answer, if its usefull